# Можно ли запустить скрипт Python3 на FreeDOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dos, freedos

Заинтересовался, можно ли запустить какой-нибудь простенький скрипт Python3 на FreeDOS?

Если да, то как это сделать, и можно ли, чтобы код запускался автоматически при запуске?

Comment: Вроде запускают micropython.

Comment: Есть собранный для DOS Python 2.4: http://www.caddit.net/pythond/

Comment: Ну и да, micropython, правда не очень понятно какой версии Python (2 или 3): https://github.com/pohmelie/micropython-freedos

Comment: "чтобы код запускался автоматически при запуске?" - можно, если мой склероз меня не подводит, нужно добавить нужную команду в AUTOEXEC.BAT (или как там этот файл назывался)

Comment: micropython видимо все же 3 (3.4, если конкретнее), так что теоретически вам может подойти: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBiVw.png Но в целом, я бы порекомендовал вместо доса использовать какой-нибудь минимальный линукс без графической оболочки. Но конечно от конкретной задачи зависит.